# Notifying SignalR clients from outside web request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 plugin-based webapp with a plugin containing a listener class, running in the background listening for messages on a SQL Server Broker queue. When new messages arrive I want to push these out to all connected clients.

I have created a notification hub, which works perfectly when sending from client to server, but the code I use to send updates to clients doesn't do anything.

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
context.Clients.All.dataUpdated(message.Data);
```

I have tried using

```
using (var timerScope = AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.ApplicationContainer.BeginLifetimeScope("httpRequest"))
{
    var connMgr = timerScope.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
    var context = connMgr.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    context.Clients.All.dataUpdated(message.Data);
}
```

but then I only get an InvalidOperationException with the error message: "The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available."

Understandable enough, since I'm trying to do make the call outside a web request.

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all? I have seen some examples using a webrequest to connect to itself to send a message, but I'm looking for a cleaner way, and I really don't want to go full fledged message bus.

Comment: You first sample should work. I don't think you need the `AutofacDependencyResolver`. `GetHubContext` does not even create your `NotificationHub`. All it does is provide an abstraction over publishing to SignalR's own internal message bus. Have you successfully called `Clients.All.dataUpdated` from inside your Hub? My guess is you wired up your client hub's `dataUpdated` method incorrectely. Can you post your client code?

Comment: Unless you replaced GlobalHost.DependencyResolver then you're using the wrong dependency resolver.

Comment: I don't really know what was the issue, since later in the day, the same code did work. I've had some issues with VS2012 crashing lately, so maybe it's connected to that. Thanks for letting me know my code was correct, halter73, so I didn't continue down the wrong path.